# Assign onClick event for Button in list item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a `ListView` that is populated from a database.Each row has a button to update the item value from the list and the database.I want to add onClick event for buttons used in item of `ListView`. How can I assign an OnClickListener for buttons for list items ?

[image]

**addtooutlet.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#ffffff">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**addtooutlet_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_bname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_bid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_bname"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Join"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="12dip" />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AddTooutlet.java**

```
 public class AddToOutlet extends ListActivity {
SessionManager session;
String success, cus_id, bus_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addtooutlet);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLoginback();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // ID
    final String cus_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_id", cus_id));
    String response = null;
    try {
 response=LoginHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_api/add_to_outlet.php",postParameters);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put("bus_name", json_data.getString("bus_name"));
            map.put("bus_id", json_data.getString("bus_id"));
            success = json_data.getString("success");
            mylist.add(map);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist,
            R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, new String[] { "bus_name",
                    "bus_id" },
            new int[] { R.id.item_bname, R.id.item_bid });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private OnClickListener callback;

    public Myadapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings, OnClickListener callback) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, parent,
                false);

        Button buttonEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.item_button);

        buttonEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i("xx", "Button pressed!");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Post your MyAdapter class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

```
 View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, parent,
            false);
```

But you return

```
return convertView;
```

Should be

```
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, parent,
            false);
```

And

```
 Button buttonEdit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
```

And

```
return convertView;
```

Edit:

As suggested in the comment by blackbelt. You are not using Custom ArrayAdapter

You probably meant

```
Myadapter adapter = new MyAdapter(ActivityName.this,R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item,mylist);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String> map;
 LayoutInflater mInflater;
 public Myadapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayLsit<HashMap<String,String> map, OnClickListener callback) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, map);
    this.map = map;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView ==null)
    {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, parent,
            false);
    holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
    convertView.setTaf(holder); 
    }else{
           holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    HashMap<String,String> hm = map.get(position);
    holder.tv1.setText(hm.get(postion).get("bus_name").toString());
    holder.tv2.setText(hm.get(postion).get("bus_id").toString());
    holder.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.i("xx", "Button pressed!");
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The ViewHodler

```
static class ViewHolder
{
     Button b;
     TextView tv1,tv2; 
}
```

Now you should have a textview's in `layout.addtooutlet_list_item.xml` and update views in getView.

Also consider using a ViewHolder Pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: but he is not using MyAdapter. He is using a SimpleAdapter. And still if what you point it out was the issue, his app was crashing

Comment: Another minor thing, you could suggest him to avoid to inflate every time the convertView

Comment: @Amardeep Look at the edited code. Only thing missing is a ViewHolder

Comment: @Raghunandan, +1 for great co-operation. as well as answer.,

Comment: @Amardeep edited further to add view holder. have 2 textviews and a button in `addtooutlet_list_item.xml`. rest all copy paste

Comment: @Raghunandan i have not completed task you have suggested...i am totally confuse..plz suggest any example.. i make customrowadapter but not get the value in listview.

Comment: @Amardeep if you use the code posted and copy paste the same it will work provided you have items in mylist.

Comment: @Amardeep Do you get any excpetions. I guess NetWorkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Raghunandan ok let me try again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48479/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-amardeep)

Comment: Hello @Raghunandan I was implemented your code in last night..I got an error in Logcat java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Raghunandan plz look at this  que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501816/search-functionality-within-list-view-in-android