# How to search a item in the dynamic ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-softkeyboard, android-search

I'm trying to develop a search function on a list of items by using adapter class.

> [image]

How to use search functionality in listview when listview get all item dyanamically from php-mysql database via json webservice.

I have post my completed code on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501816/search-functionality-within-list-view-in-android).

Comment: Have a look on this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: In this link data is static.. i am fetching data via json and adapter used to bind data in list view

Comment: Its nothing to do with static or dynamic data. Because you apply filter on Adapter. So whatever data your adapter contains it will apply to that.

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial?

Comment: i follow the tutorial but i found the error in onTextChanged method, in this line->> AddToOutlet.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50033/discussion-between-amardeep-and-user3110424)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search functionality Within List View in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501816/search-functionality-within-list-view-in-android)